# Profile GPU Rendering is running hot on app-framework - Framework7 - cordova - vue.js

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, gpu, html-framework-7

when i started developing the framework7-vue-cordova-webpack template, I noticed, that my android device gets hot and wasn't even charging. Then I checked the Profile GPU Rendering on android and saw the GPU was running sleeplessly, even when no function or touch was triggered. I thought my code was kind of in a loop, but then I installed a new instance of that framework and checked again, still too much gpu rendering for no action on the simplest template -- > see screenshot

this framework -> https://github.com/scriptPilot/app-framework

Then I tried another framework7-cordova (https://github.com/centrual/cordova-template-framework7-vue-webpack) , there I also checked and the GPU Rendering is like it has to be and not hot device.

So is this a bigger issue or am I doing something wrong?

[Screenshot: GPU running on framework7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd2Th.png)

npm -v : 5.5.1
cordova -v 7.1.0
app-framework 1.14.7
android 7.0